# Using the Max command with grouping

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dataset, max, calculated-field

I'm using SQL Server Report Builer 2008 R2, i'm self taught, while i can code in a variety of things well, i have some major knowledge blackholes so apologies if this is a really simple question!

I want to create a calculated field (Ideal Rate) which looks at the SKU number, then finds the highest recorded Target rate for that sku, thereby giving me what should of been made for each full hour, the current target rate alters based on the avaliable time in that hour (and zero's out when theres no time avaliable).

I tried using 'max' in conjuction with group but keep running into errors or incorrect information.

Time ----- SKU  --- Avaliable Time  --- Actual -- Target --- Reliability -- Ideal Rate 
00:00     -- 201168 ------ 45             ------------- 1299 -----  1500 -----  86.60%     ----- 2000
01:00   -- 201168   ------ 00            -------------  00 -------- 00  --------- 00.00%       ----- 2000
02:00   -- 201168   ------ 60            -------------  1500 -----  2000    ----- 75.00%       ----- 2000
03:00   -- 201701   ------ 57            -------------  306 ------  332.5   ----- 92.03%       ----- 350
04:00   -- 201701   ------ 60           -------------   108 ------  350 ------- 44.08%     ----- 350
05:00   -- 201701   ------ 30            -------------  109 ------  175 ------- 62.29%     ----- 350
06:00   -- 202560   ------ 45           -------------   505 -----   600 -------- 84.17%    ----- 800
07:00   -- 202560   ------ 00           -------------   00  ------- 00  --------- 00.00%       ----- 800
08:00   -- 202560   ------ 60           -------------   500 ------  800 ------- 62.50%     ----- 800
09:00   -- 201168   ------ 09           -------------   101 -----   300 -------- 33.67%    ----- 2000
10:00    -- 201168   ------ 27         -------------    606 -----   900 -------- 67.33%    ----- 2000

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide details or error you are receiving and example of incorrect information you mentioned? The following code **should** give you what you need.

```
SELECT SKU, MAX([Target])
  FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY SKU
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'd tried some code similar to yours and this is the error i was/am recieving, just to clarify i am trying to create the calculated field in the dataset rather than in a table in the report.

Comment: TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder
------------------------------

The 'Ideal2' calculated member cannot be created because of the following error:
An MDX expression was expected while a full statement was specified.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An MDX expression was expected while a full statement was specified. (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Analysis Services)

------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a sub-query to get the max rate for a given SKU like so:

```
SELECT 
     Time 
    ,SKU
    ,Avaliable_Time
    ,Actual
    ,TargetLoginName
    ,Reliability
    ,i.Rate AS Ideal_Rate
FROM
    table T
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            SKU
            ,MAX(Rate) AS Rate
        FROM
            table 
        GROUP BY
            SKU
    ) i
    ON i.SKU = T.SKU
```